# Can I optimize this kind of query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    s.last_spread, s.sd, s.mean, s.id
    ,c.id_ticker, c.coef
    ,t.ticker
    ,p.last, p.price

FROM (SELECT * FROM spreads WHERE spreads.id_check=1 LIMIT 100,500 ) as s 

    INNER JOIN coef as c 
        ON c.id_spread = s.id

    INNER JOIN tickers AS t
            ON t.id = c.id_ticker

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT prices.id_ticker, MAX(prices.date) as last, prices.price FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker) AS p
            ON p.id_ticker = t.id
```

These are the schemas of the tables:

```
mysql> desc spreads;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_check    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sd          | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mean        | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_spread | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> desc coef;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_spread | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_ticker | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| coef      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| side      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> desc tickers;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ticker   | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| issuer   | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> desc prices;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_ticker | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date      | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

These are the indexes of the above tables;

```
mysql> show indexes from spreads;
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| spreads |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |        2299 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| spreads |          1 | check_idx |            1 | id_check    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show indexes from coef;
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| coef  |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | id          | A         |        9078 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| coef  |          1 | spread_ticker_idx |            1 | id_spread   | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| coef  |          1 | spread_ticker_idx |            2 | id_ticker   | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show indexes from tickers;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tickers |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |         100 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show indexes from prices;
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| prices |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |       19962 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| prices |          1 | id_ticker |            1 | id_ticker   | A         |       19962 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

And this is the explain of the query:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref                       | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL              | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                      |    500 |             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | c          | ref    | spread_ticker_idx | spread_ticker_idx | 5       | s.id                      |     90 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | t          | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY           | 4       | spreadtrading.c.id_ticker |      1 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ALL    | NULL              | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                      |    100 |             |
|  3 | DERIVED     | prices     | index  | NULL              | id_ticker         | 4       | NULL                      | 119774 |             |
|  2 | DERIVED     | spreads    | ref    | check_idx         | check_idx         | 5       |                           |   2298 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.27 sec)
```

Could I optimize it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I would like to know if the INDEXES and the table's structure are optimized for the query I posted above. The results that I get using this query are good, it works well, but maybe I can optimize it to increse the "speed" of the query.

Comment: Wow.  What are your thoughts?  Have you tried anything?  Does the lack of a selected `key` for some tables in the `EXPLAIN` output not raise a flag? How long is the query currently taking?  Did you really think you could just dump all that information and get an answer?

Comment: Your derived query on prices is the biggest culprit. Don't use a derived query there.

Comment: @eggyal - Well, if op would've just posted his query, then **we** would've just asked him to post table structures and plans, so I think this is a very much welcome improvement from those posts

Comment: @Lamak: True.  I don't want to discourage posting the relevant information, but just presenting it with no attempt to analyse its contents...?

Comment: @Dail - I hope you're aware that without an `ORDER BY` in that `spreads` subquery, you may not be getting the rows you expect; SQL is inherently _unordered_, and (especially with that `WHERE` clause) most implementations have optimizers that tweak statements to run efficiently, which may modify result ordering.  So, you're currently getting 'random' rows.

Comment: @eggyal please take a look at the EDIT I have wrote. Thanks

Comment: @MarcusAdams I don't understand what you mean, yes the problem is the prices table because it has many rows and I only need to get the last price (so i need to get the last date to know the last price)

Comment: @X-Zero I must to use the limit there, I tried to put it at the end but it truncate useful rows that belongs to coef

Comment: @Lamak thank you! I have difficult reading the EXPLAIN result. Is this query using all the indexes? Thanks!

Comment: @X-Zero hmm do I have to do something to improve the ordering?

Comment: You have to add an explicit `ORDER BY` to restrict the rows the way you expect.  Also, you are **NOT GUARANTEED** to get the 'last' price with your current statement - if you don't wrap a column in a statement that has a `GROUP BY` (and it's not a column in that clause), you get what amounts to a **RANDOM** row (this behaviour is unique to mySQL - most other RDBMSs I know simply disallow the attempt, for precisely this reason).

Comment: @X-Zero I do: SELECT prices.id_ticker, MAX(prices.date) as last, prices.price FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker why is it not guaranteed?

Comment: Because you're (probably) going to be getting the 'first' `price` encountered when linked from an index (by row) by a table probe.  The order can be any one of the following for a given `id_ticker` (and you have no direct control over it) - the most recent inserted row (not the most recent _effective_ row), the _oldest_ inserted row, the row with `MAX(prices.date)` (supposing there's an index including that); basically, the more indicies you have, the **worse** your chances of actually getting the (unspecified) row you want is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may gain something by dropping the `spreads` subquery and moving the `WHERE` clause to the end, as in the following code.  This loses your `LIMIT` restriction - perhaps you could put a `LIMIT` clause at the end as well, depending on what you're trying to achieve in terms of limiting the size of the output.

```
SELECT 
    s.last_spread, s.sd, s.mean, s.id
    ,c.id_ticker, c.coef
    ,t.ticker
    ,p.last, p.price

FROM  spreads as s 

    INNER JOIN coef as c 
        ON c.id_spread = s.id

    INNER JOIN tickers AS t
            ON t.id = c.id_ticker

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT prices.id_ticker, MAX(prices.date) as last, prices.price FROM prices GROUP BY prices.id_ticker) AS p
            ON p.id_ticker = t.id
WHERE s.id_check = 1
```

Comment: I didn't notice this before, but `prices.price` is neither grouped, nor wrapped in an aggregate function - this means it's returning a 'random' row - do you have any recommendations to fix this?